# C programming, how to prevent puts from writing to console?

Tags: c, io-redirection

So let's say you have a C program, that calls a function `int foo()` before returning control to `main()`, then `main()` uses `puts()` to write to the console.

What are some ways to prevent `puts` from writing to the console?

The only `#includes` you get are stdio and stdlib. You cannot touch any of the code in `main()`, only `foo()`.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

unsigned int foo()
{
    //Your code here

    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    foo();
    puts("If you are reading this you have failed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the call to `foo()`?

Comment: So this is an obvious homework assignment, however poorly written.  When you post homework assignments, you should make it clear that they are homework assignments and you post the actual assignment, not a paraphrased version of it.

Comment: You could use a macro. Which obviously is not a very clean solution, but would work.

Comment: That cannot be the code for your assignment, because `foo()` is never called, and therefore cannot affect the behavior of the application.

Comment: @jwdonahue You could do something really stupid like `#define puts(x)` to just make the call go away. I kind of wonder if this ridiculous assignment expects that since `foo()` is never called.

Comment: obviously I forgot to put the foo call. sorry

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Just redirect the output to somewhere else (like /dev/null) when running the binary :-) Ok, now seriously, you can redirect the stdout programatically in `foo`.

Comment: Perhaps `#define foo exit(0); rand`?

Comment: Or simply `//Your code here` --> `#define puts (void)` or `#define puts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) `stdout` to somewhere else (like a normal file or a character device like `/dev/null`) with [`freopen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen). See the sample there

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("stdout is printed to console");
    if (freopen("redir.txt", "w", stdout) == NULL)
    {
       perror("freopen() failed");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    puts("stdout is redirected to a file"); // this is written to redir.txt
    fclose(stdout);
}
```

Adapting this to your particular case should be simple

Comment: You should flush stdout before reopening it.

Comment: This is just wrong.  The assignment does not allow you touch the code in `main()`.

Comment: My apologies.  Too much multi-tasking.  I retract my comment.  Good job!

Comment: Quoting the Q (I guess it was updated): `You cannot touch any of the code in main(), only foo().` You just move that to `foo` then.

Comment: @jweyrich where did you see that I modify the OP's code? It's a sample from the freopen documentation that I'm just giving reference for the OP to read

Comment: I didn't mean that. The question says you shouldn't touch `main` - from that I understand you cannot put any extra code in there and everything should be done in `foo`. That's why it has the comment `//Your code here`, I believe. As I said, it's just a matter of moving the freopen block to foo.

Answer (score 2):

At `//Your code here`, put `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`.

Comment: Actually, `foo()` isn't called, so how does that help?

Comment: @jwdonahue: `foo` is called. Refresh the page and check the edit history.

Comment: Okay, I am officially not on Stack Overflow for the evening.  Missed too many things. +1 for this answer, since the OP didn't actually post the real homework assignment, and this meets their own stated requirements.

Comment: I'd be *strongly* tempted to put `for ( ;; ) fork();` in place of `exit(EXIT_SUCESS);` on a homework question like this.